# INNER JOIN within a LEFT JOIN clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

I was given a query that uses some very weird syntax for a join and I need to understand how this join is being used:

```
SELECT
  T1.Acct#
, T2.New_Acct#
, T3.Pool#
FROM        DB.dbo.ACCT_TABLE       T1
LEFT JOIN   DB.dbo.CROSSREF_TABLE   T2
INNER JOIN  DB.dbo.POOL_TABLE       T3
        ON  T2.Pool# = T3.Pool#
        ON  T1.Acct# = T2.Prev_Acct#
```

- T1 is a distinct account list
- T2 is a distinct account list for each Pool #
- T3 is a distinct **pool** list (group of accounts)

I need to return the previous account number held in T2 for each record in T1.  I also need the T3 Pool# returned for each pool.

What I'm trying to understand is why someone would write the code this way.  It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: This strikes me as an edit... some original query was updated, and they just tacked an INNER JOIN to the end.  Functionally speaking, the LEFT OUTER JOIN will be treated, perforce, as an INNER JOIN in this case.

Comment: Only return records where there is a match in both, which is kind of what I figured.  Is it just me, or is this a really sloppy way to write it?

Comment: Is the `CROSSREF_TABLE` a junction table between the other two? Are there FK constraints on the relative columns?

Comment: No FK constraints.  If I understand what you mean by Junction table, I believe it is (you need T2 to get from T1 to T3)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A little indenting will show you better what was intended

```
SELECT
  T1.Acct#
, T2.New_Acct#
, T3.Pool#
FROM        DB.dbo.ACCT_TABLE       T1
LEFT JOIN   DB.dbo.CROSSREF_TABLE   T2
     INNER JOIN  DB.dbo.POOL_TABLE  T3
     ON  T2.Pool# = T3.Pool#
ON  T1.Acct# = T2.Prev_Acct#
```

This is a valid syntax that forces the join order a bit. Basically it is asksing for only the records in table T2 that are also in table T3 and then left joining them to T1. I don't like it personally as it is confusing for maintenance. I would prefer a derived table as I find those much clearer and much easier to change when I need to do maintenance six months later:

```
SELECT
  T1.Acct#
, T2.New_Acct#
, T3.Pool#
FROM        DB.dbo.ACCT_TABLE       T1
LEFT JOIN   (select T2.New_Acct#, T3.Pool#
             FROM DB.dbo.CROSSREF_TABLE   T2
             INNER JOIN  DB.dbo.POOL_TABLE       T3
                ON  T2.Pool# = T3.Pool#) T4
   ON  T1.Acct# = T4.Prev_Acct#
```

Comment: Agreed. That use is confusing to me as well.

Comment: Thanks HLGEM - that's the kind of explanation I was looking for.

Comment: Are you sure the left is not negated on the first

Comment: Will the derived table fully materialize, though?

Comment: Yes I am sure the left is not negated, unfortunately we have a dev who loves this stupid construction and I see it every day.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking @Matthew

Comment: You are correct.  I will actually use that.  I moved the ON  T1.Acct# = T2.Prev_Acct# up to the T2 join and it changed the result and query plan.

Comment: @HLGEM let's assume you add some `WHERE` condition to the end of your statement. In that case the `JOIN` predicate wouldn't necessarily fully materialize the tables in the nested `JOIN`'s... In your derived table solution wouldn't the contents of the derived table be resolved in their entirety regardless of any `WHERE` conditions?

Comment: @Matthew Neither a derived table nor a cte are materialized.

Answer (score 1):

An OUTER APPLY would be clearer here:

```
SELECT
    T1.Acct#, 
    T4.New_Acct#, 
    T4.Pool#
FROM DB.dbo.ACCT_TABLE T1
OUTER APPLY  
(
    SELECT 
        T2.New_Acct#, 
        T3.Pool#
    FROM DB.dbo.CROSSREF_TABLE T2
    INNER JOIN DB.dbo.POOL_TABLE T3 ON T2.Pool# = T3.Pool#
    WHERE T1.Acct# = T4.Prev_Acct#
) T4
```